# How to rotate a Globe, So that when selecting a position on globe using mouse click on it don't tilt the Globe sideways?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have achieved Globe rotating on mouse click on any particular panel on the Globe and the panel position gets in the Center of the Camera on click but the problem is Globe travels the shortest distance between the two points (Camera Center and Next Position on Globe).

As per the image currently Globe jumps to next position and tilts like this

[image]

As per this Image I need Globe to result in this rotation where NorthPole and SouthPole remains at their side looking through the camera.

[image]

```
public List<GameObject> characters = new List<GameObject>();
private Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;

public void CharacterPosition(int charNum)
{
    Quaternion diff = Quaternion.FromToRotation(characters[charNum].transform.up, camera.transform.position - transform.position);
    targetRotation = diff * transform.rotation;
    transform.DORotateQuaternion(targetRotation, 1f);
    hitAgainNumber = charNum;
}
```

"characters" List conists of the panels on the globe on multiple positions.
DoTween Plugin is used for the Rotation.

I will be very thankful if someone helps me with that.

Comment: why `Quaternion.FromToRotation(characters[charNum].transform.up, camera.transform.position - transform.position);`? wouldn't you rather want `characters[charNum].transform.forward` ?

Comment: @derHugo No because I used `characters[charNum].transform.up` to get the normal of the plane, which was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanations are in the comments:

```
public List<GameObject> characters = new List<GameObject>();
private Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;

public void CharacterPosition(int charNum)
{      
    // Use cross products to find the closest vector to Vector3.up which is orthogonal
    // to the direction from the sphere to the camera. 
    // This direction is to be the sprite's forward after we rotate the sphere
    Vector3 charGoalUp = camera.transform.position - transform.position;
    Vector3 charGoalRight = Vector3.Cross(charGoalUp, Vector3.up);
    Vector3 charGoalForward = Vector3.Cross(charGoalRight, charGoalUp);

    // Get the goal rotation for the character using `LookRotation`:
    Quaternion charGoalRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(charGoalForward, charGoalUp);

    // Determine the world rotation that needs to apply to the character:
    // delta * char_start = char_end -> delta = char_end * inv(char_start)
    Quaternion worldCharDelta = charGoalRotation 
            * Quaternion.Inverse(characters[charNum].transform.rotation);

    // Apply that same world rotation to the globe:
    targetRotation = worldCharDelta * transform.rotation;

    transform.DORotateQuaternion(targetRotation, 1f);
    hitAgainNumber = charNum;

}
```

Comment: I am having just one issue when I implement this code on Globe and try to use the Globe in AR then the character doesn't always face the camera, it rotates in front of the camera but not in the center of it.

Comment: @VarunSaini It's hard to understand what you mean without a picture. Can you include a screenshot of that in the question?

Comment: In the above pictures in the question, camera position is (0,0,-10). If I change the camera position to something else with different position and rotation the character will not result in the Center of the Camera.

https://imgur.com/a/xSnZ7yX
In this Image Camera Position is (0,5,-10) and Rotation is (25,0,0). The Character should be in the center as per the Image. But its not happening like this. The next picture explains what I am getting in result.
https://imgur.com/1ucTHsR.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @VarunSaini I tested it out on my machine and found the fix. That should work for you.

Comment: Thank you mate. The updated code works as per my requirement and tested it in AR too. 

I have another problem in the same project, Would you like to help me in that too?

Comment: @VarunSaini Sure, feel free to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)